# Ambiguous error from flow-type on useImperativeHandle which cannot resolve

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a functional component which use **useImperativeHandle**,

```
const ConfirmActionModal = (props: Props, ref) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsVisible(true)
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      showModal: showModal
    }
  })

  ...
  return (
      // html
  )
}

export default forwardRef<Props, void>(ConfirmActionModal)
```

I'm getting a **flow-type** error

```
Cannot call useImperativeHandle with function bound to create because:
 • object literal [1] is incompatible with enum [2] in the return value.
 • object literal [1] is incompatible with enum [3] in the return value.

        src/apps/orders/ConfirmActionModal.js
         57│   //   }
         58│   // })
         59│
    [1]  60│   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
         61│     showModal() {
         62│       showModal()
         63│     }
         64│   }))
         65│
         66│   const node: { current: null | HTMLDivElement } = useRef(null)
         67│   const stateRef = useRef(isVisible)

        /tmp/flow/flowlib_1890a56b/react.js
 [3][2] 292│       ref: {current: null | Instance} | ((null | Instance) => mixed),



Found 2 errors
```

As I understand type which is defined in flow, which is following

```
  declare export function useImperativeHandle<T>(
    ref: {current: T | null} | ((inst: T | null) => mixed) | null | void,
    create: () => T,
    inputs: ?$ReadOnlyArray<mixed>,
  ): void;
```

doesn't work with definition of forwardRef

```
  declare export function forwardRef<Config, Instance>(
    render: (
      props: Config,
      ref: {current: null | Instance} | ((null | Instance) => mixed),
    ) => React$Node,
  ): React$AbstractComponent<Config, Instance>;
```

I found a github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8092) related to this but the conversation hasn't evolved. Further more I found this [article](https://medium.com/flow-type/supporting-react-forwardref-and-beyond-f8dd88f35544) from flow it which says.

> If your component is a function, you probably want to rethink your use
> of forwardRef, since the instance type of a function component is
> void.

I wonder why

P.S
following is userInperativeHandle function on react source code. There is no type information there.

```
function useImperativeHandle(ref, create, inputs) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useImperativeHandle(ref, create, inputs);
}
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like it's related to the fact that you've made your ref instance `void` instead of something like `HTMLElement` or `HTMLInputElement` so when you pass it into `useImperativeHandle` flow will assume you're passing `void` which isn't valid. But it would help if you can provide documentation for `useImperativeHandle` so we can understand what it requires

Comment: Hi @Brianzchen, It should be Instance but for some reason I cannot import Instance to my file. Since it said for functional components void is the return type I tried that and it worked. May be I just fooled flow-type. 

About `useImperativeHandle` I don't think so. Since function is wrapped by forwardRef as per flow definition it is Instance then `useImperativeHandle` should return Instance too. Which I find ambiguous.